# MySQL Inconsistent Data Retrieval

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, gwt

I am having issues with the inconsistent result when I retrieve data from the database. These are the two cases:

1) There are times when it outputs the complete expected rows and sometimes it's not complete. For example, there are really 5 rows in the database but there are times when this is retrieved from the search function of my system, it is only 3 and sometimes it returns the complete 5 rows. It will return the complete 5 rows for some time but after a while, it will return just the 3. The search button that triggers this retrieval is clicked just milliseconds after the first search. This seems to happen randomly. I am using the same search function on my system.

2) There are times when the data retrieved has the new values just saved, and sometimes it has the old values. Again, this seems to happen randomly.

Is this has anything to do with the cache? Sometimes it gets from the cache but sometimes it gets from the actual database? Or is it the mysql-connector installed?

This is a GWT-developed system installed on a tomcat server. The tomcat server is installed using the bitnami stack tomcat installer.

The following is the context.xml:

```
    <Resource name="MYSQLDB"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="500" maxIdle="30" maxWait="60000"
    username="f1db" password="systema01" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    poolPreparedStatements="true"
    maxOpenPreparedStatements="20"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
    testOnBorrow="true"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    logAbandoned="true"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/f1db?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

Does anyone know what's causing this inconsistency in data retrieval? I already spent days debugging this but still can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding these fields to your context file cachingAllowed="false" and cacheTTL="1000".

Comment: could it be caused by old stale db connections that have not been closed?